# VLOOKUP on all sheets

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a "Master" sheet with part numbers in column A and locations in column B. I have approx 200 sheets with just part numbers in column A. How can I apply VLOOKUP to all sheets so every part number on every sheet will have my location in column B? It will take forever to do it manually.  Thanks

Comment: Write a macro that loops through all 200 sheets and insert a `vlookup` formula into column B of every sheet.

Comment: Are the sheets with part numbers named and ordered or sorted in any way?

Comment: All sheets have a job name (Job-123-top, Job-123-btm) etc. and are sorted in the best numerical order as they can be.

Comment: Your workbook is a db mess. You should consider put all your data within one sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve a lookup of data from the `Master` Sheet, assuming the starting cell containing your lookup value is `A2`. This also assumes that all sheets are in the same workbook:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Master!$A$2:$B$11,2)
```

An explanation of what each argument does from left to right:

- `A2` - cell containing lookup value in one of the 200 sheets. (This can be any cell which contains a lookup value).
- `Master` is the name of the sheet which contains the data to look up.
- `$A$2` is the top left cell for the table data to look up in the `Master` sheet, we want to use $ sign because the lookup table top left cell should be fixed.
- `$B$11` is the bottom right cell for the table to look up in the `Master` sheet, we want to use $ sign because the lookup table bottom right cell should be fixed.
- `2`, this is the column index which includes value you want returned for a successful look up. The column index starts at 1 and increases to the right, The column at index 1 contains the lookup values. In your scenario, index 1 is Column A and specifying an index of 2 will index column B

To deal with blank cells or cells which are not found in the table you can extend this formula like so:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Master!$A$2:$B$11,2)),"",VLOOKUP(A2,Master!$A$2:$B$11,2))
```

This formula will do the lookup, if it does not find the value it is looking for it will leave the cell blank, otherwise it populates the cell with the found data.

You can now copy and paste to cell `A2` (or replace `A2` with starting cell) and then drag the formula down the column to the last cell that requires `VLOOKUP` from the data table in the `Master` sheet. For every row X, it will update the lookup return data for the corresponding lookup value.

You will need to copy the formula then drag it to fill the entire B column for each 200 sheets which is a bit tedious. An alternative is to write a macro which loops over each sheet in the workbook and populates the corresponding column with the result of the lookup from the Master sheet.

`VLOOKUP` works when the lookup value is in some column X and the value to return, the data, is to the right of X.

If the data to be returned is to the left of the lookup value, you must use a combination of `MATCH` and `INDEX` which is slightly more complicated.

To lookup data in a different workbook, you will need to create a link between the two workbooks, [this article explains how to do so.](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2447199&seqNum=2)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. For some reason it copies the same location for all until it finds the next location before the location number changes.  To clarify.. my MASTER sheet has part numbers in column A and locations in Column B.  All sheets have Part numbers in Column A

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand the problem. When you say "it copies the same location for all until it finds the next location before the location number changes", do you mean you have gaps in your column A data for the 200 sheets and it is copying the last found lookup value to the cells with empty lookup values?

Comment: Yes, it looks like thats exactly what its doing based on your question.

Comment: To fix this you need to do some error checking.
Please see the original answer which I have updated with the error checking formula. This formula will do the lookup, if it does not find the value it is looking for it will leave the cell blank, otherwise it populates the cell with the found data.

Comment: It finds the location which happens to be the first part number in column A and returns the location from column B, but still copies that same location for the rest of the parts until it finds the next location and then does the same thing.

Comment: It sounds like your data might not have an exact match. You can tell the formula to find an extact match or to find closest match by adding the parameter TRUE or FALSE respectively. Like this:   VLOOKUP(A2,Master!$A$2:$B$11,2,TRUE)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142837/discussion-between-sparkplug-and-noob2java).

Answer (score 0):

Think about changing all your data to a single sheet. You may try this home made function:

```
Function AllSheetVLookup(ByVal lookup_value, ByVal search_col As Long, ByVal return_col As Long, Optional book_rng As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In IIf(book_rng Is Nothing, Application.Caller, book_rng).Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets
        r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(lookup_value, ws.Columns(search_col), 0)
        If r Then AllSheetVLookup = ws.Cells(r, return_col): Exit Function
    Next
    AllSheetVLookup = CVErr(2042) 'Not found, #N/A! returned
End Function
```

`lookup_value` - value to search, has in VLOOKUP;
`search_col` - column number in worksheets where to search for value
`return_col` - column number to return value from matched with match
`book_rng` - optional. Cell in another book if another book is to be searched. If ommited, book where function is called is used.

Example:

```
=AllSheetVLookup("part_number", 1, 2)
```

Will search for value "part_number" in column A (1st) from all worksheets of current book, and return value of column B (2nd).

Comment: thanks @LS_dev   The reason I cannot put all data in one sheet is that I am using the individual sheets for jobs. So each part needs to have a location next to it.   I'm not quite sure how to use this function?

Comment: Could be a formatting issue  @sparkplug   I found this and it seems to work. Now if could figure out how to apply this formula to column B in ALL sheets with automation, I would be set.  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1&"",MASTER!$A$1:$B$7,2,FALSE),"")

Comment: @Noob2Java I don't know what are your limitation but for sake of normalization, your jobs should put all data in one sheet, with an additional column for job identification.